# Problem with indentation in Sublime Text 4

Tags: javascript, sublimetext, indentation

I am suddenly having some problems with indentation in my Sublime Text 4 editor.
When I press Enter on a curly brace, it shows this behavior

[image]

instead of this, as it should normally work (and the way it was working one week back when I last used Sublime Text 4)

[image]

I've tried tweaking the Preferences, but it's not getting fixed.
Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Close voters: From [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the [help], software questions are allowed if they cover *"[...] software tools commonly used by programmers".* Sublime Text, like Vim, Emacs, VSCode, etc., is a programming editor, and there are [tens of thousands of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vim+or+vi+or+emacs+or+visual-studio-code) about them on this site that are perfectly on-topic. This question is on-topic both here and on [su].

Comment: did you install a new package for syntax highlighting recently?

Comment: Indeed; this looks like a key binding issue